# IntelliJ issues error for 'false' value in yaml

Tags: intellij-idea

Whenever in `.yml` file that I have a `false` property value I am getting a inspection error from IntelliJ. This happened only recently, I am using IntelliJ 2019.3.5

> Invalid value 'false', must be one of off|on|true|true
> Inspection info: Checks Spring Boot application .yaml configuration files. Highlights unresolved and deprecated configuration keys and invalid values.

The application runs fine but I'd like to know what causes this and if I should turn the inspection off.

Comment: Could you please try 2020.1.4 release: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html? Does the issue persist?

Comment: @CrazyCoder The error is gone. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please always try the latest available product version before reporting bugs.

The issue seems to be fixed and not reproducible in the [current IDE release](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html).

The better place to report IntelliJ IDEA bugs would be [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA).